# span Element shown in the single line

Tags: css

i have made the span element in the div.

```
<div id="maindiv" style="max-width: 50%;margin: auto;">
<span id="span1">span1</span>
<span id="span2">span2</span>
<span id="span3">span3</span>
<span id="span4">span4</span>
<span id="span5">span5</span>
<span id="span6">span6</span>
<span id="span7">span7</span>
<span id="span8">span8</span>
<span id="span9">span9</span>
<span id="span10">span10</span>
<span id="span11">span11</span>
<span id="span12">span12</span>
<span id="span13">span13</span>
<span id="span14">span14</span>
<span id="span15">span15</span>
<span id="span16">span16</span>
<span id="span17">span17</span>
<span id="span18">span18</span>
<span id="span19">span19</span>
<span id="span20">span20</span>
```

problem is div in center but the span shown in single line not in second line like wrap-word.scroll are shown in the horizontal

Comment: You want each span on its own line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span is a inline element, no wonder. If you want them in dif. lines, use HTML block level element, (div, or p)or maybe use flexbox on your #maindiv

```
#maindiv{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: for use this the one span element show in one line.

Comment: my problem is if the main div width complete  the span element move on next line

Comment: You want to owerflow the spawns like this? 
div {
  display:flex;
  overflow: scroll;
}

Answer (score 1):

Write css in span tag like

```
span{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: display block show the only one span element in one line .

Comment: my problem is if the div width complete the span element move on next line

Comment: if u give display block property in span tag then all span tag come in its own line

Comment: in this case all span element shown in one by one line

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
span{
      display:inline;
    }
```